# Python.exe taking too much RAM for a simple for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code works fine if I just run it **after commenting out the for loop**, however if I don't it quickly takes up 90% of my RAM and forces my PC to crash. 
Could someone please explain whats going on?

```
from glob import glob  # used for finding the path names
import shutil
import os


def loadLikes(path):
    os.chdir(path)
    files = glob('*.jpg')
    print(type(files))
    c = len(files)
    for image in files:
        files.append(path + "/" + image)
    return files


print(loadLikes("like"))
```

Comment: You do realize that you're appending to the sequence you're iterating over, right?

Comment: You are appending to `files` while iterating through `files`. Never do this

Comment: Depending of what you want to do with `files` you could try to `yield` them instead of appending to a list

Comment: You are appending to the list while you loop over it. This causes the for loop to never terminate, since you invariabley `.append`, and this will keep happening until you are out of memory.

Comment: Did you do *any* debugging of this code?

Comment: do yourself a favor, and `print(files)` anywhere within that for loop

Comment: Oh shucks !!!
@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams thanks. I soo did not see that :3
Now I just feel stupid :3

Answer (score 0):

```
return [path + '/' + image for image in files]
```